# The definition of the words "Word Up!" and "code word"

Tags: slang, definition

I like and liked this song for a long time since I heard when it was sung by Melanny B ( Spice girls ). However, I am afraid, what does the word "word up!" mean and its lyric says it's a "code word" and what on the earth does it mean ( I mean, in the context of the entire "meaning" of the song ). Let me thank you in advance.

Cameo's song with its lyric
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1_fGgNs_PcM

- I checked any dictionary and have surfed throught the net, but the result of the meaning of the word "word up!" is, "listen to me" or "it's cool! ( or nice )". Could anyone help me please.

Comment: KS, it actually means many things. The song originally by Cameo (then covered by Melanie B, Korn, Gun, ...) uses the word in the same sense- "listen to me". However, like many words and phrases it has more than one meaning. (It is also related to 'word', 'what's the word", etc.)

Comment: Thank you, Gary. I would not like to say this, thank you for your comment, but I actually was not able to go through it precisely. After all, to understand this kind of "slang-like" words, I need to be more a native speaker like..... Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

"word up" is like saying "right on" or "that's right".

A "code word" is a shared secret word which signifies something else. A code word might be used to let people know that you're part of their social group.